# mongodb num_rows equivalent php

Tags: php, mongodb

how can i get the number of results, equivalent to `num_rows`(mysqli) in `mongodb`?

if i have

```
$db->$dbName->find(array("email" => $newemail, "password" => $newpass));
```

what is the best way to check the number of results that match this criteria?
in mysqli i would do something like

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE email='%s' AND password='%s'";
$query = sprintf($sql, $newemail, $newpass);
$result = $conn->query($query);
$rows = $result->num_rows;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this, I think:

```
$collection = $connection->myDB->myCollection;
$cursor = $collection->find(array("email" => $newemail, "password" => $newpass));
$nResults = $cursor->count();
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Cursor::count() in php file.Please suggest

Comment: The Cursor object has been reworked.  See here for a discussion, and possible solutions:  https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/195

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are using returns a MongoCursor so you can use its method [count](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.count.php) to get the number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the `count()` is that of the criteria not of the `skip` and `limit`. This is slightly different to MySQLi driver in PHP since that takes the `LIMIT` into consideration.

In order to understand the true count if you are using skips and limits you will be required to actually transform the cursor into an array or use the count() function again providing a param within its signature: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.count.php setting it to true *should* get you only those results actually found taking sip and limit into consideration.

Otherwise for your example there, as others say, you can use `count` as normal. For the example you have provided I would probably actually use `findOne`.

Comment: wouldnt `findOne` bring up the first item that matched the criteria?

Comment: @tq You should only have one person of that email and password...should

Comment: yes but in the event there are duplicate emails, i would `return false`

Comment: @tq No you would return the first one.

Comment: @tq I doubt many people for that query would haqve the same hashed password either, especially if you use a random byte range (as you should) for the salt of the password. The probability of getting two identical rows for that query would be...well too little to calculate for me.