# What is the equivalent of PHP's mysqli_num_rows() in MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb

## Specification

**Database**: [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com) 3.4

**Programming Language**: [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/) 7.1

**Library**: [PHP library of MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/) 1.2.0

## Sample Code

```
$result = $connection->db->collection->find($filter, $options);
```

In MySQL, you do this:

```
$number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

When trying things out and doing some research, I've tried this:

```
$number_of_rows = $result->count();
```

It returns this error since it's part of the [legacy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.count.php) (not included in the [MongoDB driver](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-cursor.php)):

```
Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Cursor::count()
```

When I tried using count() or sizeof(), the result is always 1.

```
$number_of_rows = count($result);

$number_of_rows = sizeof($result);
```

How should it be done properly in this version (or the latest version 3.6) of MongoDB without having to iterate a $count variable inside a for-loop?

*Same question but outdated answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098647/mongodb-num-rows-equivalent-php)*.

Comment: [db.collection.count()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/)

Comment: @AlivetoDie From the command line, yes, and yes, you can even filter through find what needs to be counted. But I've posted the sample code above to indicate the need to retrieve the number of results after find() has been executed.

Comment: Hope this helps.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12098786/4903314

Comment: @MikeDaVinci That's the same link I posted in my question (the bottom part that has been italicised). It's outdated. The answer is for the older version (I've also posted a link in the question pointing to the documentation of the legacy code).

Answer (score 2):

I expanded @Yury-Fedorov's answer to these 3 options. I have tested this and it should work on your end.

## Option 1

```
$filter = ['field' => 'value'];
$db = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
$command = new \MongoDB\Driver\Command(['count' => $collection_name, 'query' => $filter]);
try {
    $cursor = $db->executeCommand($database_name, $command);
} catch (\MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
}
$count = $cursor->toArray()[0]->n;
```

## Option 2

```
$filter = ['field' => 'value'];
$options = ['option' => 'value'];
$db = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
$query = new \MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
try {
    $cursor = $db->executeQuery("$database_name.$collection_name", $query);
} catch (\MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
}
$count = count($cursor->toArray());
```

## Option 3

```
$filter = ['field' => 'value'];
$options = ['option' => 'value'];
$db = new \MongoDB\Client ('mongodb://localhost:27017');
try {
    $cursor = $db->{$database_name}->{$collection_name}->find($filter, $options);
} catch (\MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
}
$count = count($cursor->toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `$collection->count()` method instead of `$result->count()`:

```
$query = []; // your criteria
$collection->count($query);
```

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/issues/125) discussion or at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42117273/mongodb-connector-for-php-count-documents-for-pagination/42117604#42117604) to another MongoDB count with PHP question, which is not exactly the same is this one.